# How do I send an array of hashes as a parameter in a jQuery.get() request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of hashes in Javascript, which I need to send as a parameter in a jQuery.get() request. I've tried this:

```
$.get('../notes/notes_temp_path',{temp_param:notes_array}, function(data) {
    console.log("done");                
});
```

but the server doesn't get the `temp_param` parameter. What do I need to do? Thanks for reading.

EDIT:

If I do

```
for (index in notes_array) {
    console.log(notes_array[index]);
}
console.log(window.JSON.stringify(notes_array));
```

I get

```
[ ]
 note_name    "note1"
[ ]
 note_name    "note2"
[[],[]]
```

The server receives this as well:

```
"temp_param"=>"[[],[]]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice would be to `json'ize` the array.

```
$.get('../notes/notes_temp_path',{temp_param: window.JSON.stringify(notes_array)}, function(data) {
    console.log("done");                
});
```

whatever serverside language you use, you need to `parse` that JSON-string and use it further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, couldn't get it working though. I edited details into the question.

Comment: Actually it works, not sure what was happening before. Thanks for your help!